# Xcode how to create custom tab bar item with standard system icon but with custom title

Tags: interface-builder, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to create a custom tab bar item with a custom title but I do want to use a standard system icon.

Here's my code:

```
UITabBarItem *aboutUsItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag: 0];
    overOnsItem.title = @"About us";

    self.tabBarItem = AboutUsItem;
```

but this does't work..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **What** doesn't work? Are there error messages?

Comment: Well, it just does't do a thing, no error messages or something. Just now showing...

Comment: From the documentation: "This method returns a system-supplied tab bar item. The title and image properties of the returned item cannot be changed later." You would have to get the icon and then create a `UITabBarItem` with this icon and your own title, but Apple tends to frown upon that.